# MySql results that were not found, how to get result without a match?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-select-db

I am running a query like this:

```
select x from table where c in ('variable','test','ok')
```

I get the results for all the matching C. (variable and test)
But because ok doesn't exist in c I don't get anything. Not even a null or 0 result.

How can I say to mysql that I want a result even if it doesn't find a match for a term in the in condition?

example:

```
result 
x = 12
x = 25
x = NOT FOUND
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: See UNION, or handle the logic at the application level

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understand the problem, but I guess you mean that you want X column value if `c in ('variable','test','ok')`, and if not, you want `'NOT FOUND'`?
Move the `IN` condition from the `WHERE` clause to the `select` list:

```
select case when c in ('variable','test','ok') then x
       else 'NOT FOUND' end
from table
```

Or, perhaps you mean that if no rows at all returned, you want one single `'NOT FOUND'` row? Do `UNION ALL` with that row.

```
select x from table where c in ('variable','test','ok')
UNION ALL
select 'NOT FOUND'
from (select count(*) as cnt from table
       where c in ('variable','test','ok') t
where cnt = 0
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Your answer is very good, but this way the query will search and give result for all the records in the table  and return NOT FOUND for all except the variable and test.
What I want is to search for these 3 terms, give me x for the 2 that exist in the table and for the third give a not found result.

Answer (score 1):

The usual approach for this is an outer join that joins a subquery for your fixed data and your actual table:

```
select v1.name, coalesce(t.x, 'NOT FOUND')
from (
  select 'variable' as name union all
  select 'test' union all
  select 'x') v1
left join t on t.c = v1.name
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/94ba4/1)